# Display child values in parent view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really having trouble with what I would think is a relatively easy problem, and probably very easily rectified with something I am perhaps doing wrongly.

I have a Person model, and a Department model.

The relationships are a Person has_one :department, and Department belongs_to :person

In my view, when I'm looping to gather the person's attributes, I want to be able to access the Department name. I have the department_id as a foreign key in the Person table, so I can see the valid ID for each persons department, but how can I point this id to retrieve the department name.

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.name %>
    <%= p.tel_num %>
    <%= p.department_id %>   <- i want this to somehow display the name of department
<% end %>
```

I have tried various things, p.department.name, p.department_id.name

NO LUCK!!

Very frustrating because I know its a very easy issue.

Any help much appreciated.

---

***Update:***

Sure heres my code:

Department model:

```
Class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :person
end
```

Person model:

```
Class Person < ActiveRecord::BAse
    belongs_to :department
end
```

Show Person View:

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
<p>Name: <%= "#{p.name}" %> </p>
<p>Start Date: <%= "#{p.start_date}" %> </p>
<p>Current Department: <%= "#{p.department_id}" %> <- displays relevant id
<% end %>
```

The person_department_id is being returned as 2, which would relate to "Accounts" in the department table, so thats fine.

When altering to your relations, and amending the view to: <%= p.department.name %> I still get the

```
undefined method `department' for #<Person:0x47f9040>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got relationship (hasone-belongsto) opposite way. Foreign key is supposed to be on 'belonging' side, department in your case.

So, you'll have to either update your database schema or switch `has_one` and `belongs_to` in your models.

You can read more on the subject [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one).

PS Also worth noting, it's very strange organization where every department consist of exactly one person.

**edit** On new data
You're inconsistent in your code. You used `p.department_id` in original post and `p.person_department_id` later.
Note, rails can't read foreign key name from your mind, so *modelname*_id is assumed by default. If you want something different, [specify value explicitly](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-foreign_key).

Also, please do post updated code in your question rather than a new answer. Somebody might get confused.

Comment: It would not make sense to insert a person_id into the departments table, I only have 3 departments, and just use that table to hold them. Ill try switching the relations, but again, how can I extrude the department name value within my view????

Comment: @snomy_mcnoodle `p.department.name` Really, official rails guide isn't such a hard thing to read.

Comment: undefined method `department' for #<Person:0x47f9040>

Comment: I will read the link you gave me, but I understand the concepts of the relationships and all other things work which Ive done, This is simple, but it just wont work!!!!!

Comment: @snomy_mcnoodle Checks. 1) In `Person` there's `belongs_to :department`, 2) in `Department` there's `has_one :person`, 3) `department_id` isn't nil (you can print it in your view and see).  Otherwise, posting your code might help.

Comment: So I read through the guide, I understood, I had the relations the wrong way around. So I switched them. A person belongs_to a department and a department has_one person. It doesnt make sense, but I want to model the fact a person has ONE current department.

Comment: @snomy_mcnoodle `belongs_to` is a one-to-one relationship, I'm not sure why you think it doesn't make sense. It's just a rails way to denote dependent side.

Comment: Yeah you are right, it makes sense! Just sounds a bit obtuse!

Comment: Yes it was a mistype, its been corrected now, p.department_id

Comment: Oh I am new to this site, sure I will edit my original question, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: However, even if I add the foreign_key => "department_id", I am still seeing the same error. Thats why Im posting, something just isnt right here. I understand the associations should enable this to work, but in the view when I specify p.department.name, I either get nil, or undefined method department

Comment: Could it be something to do with routes?

Comment: @snomy_mcnoodle Not likely. I'm out of ideas, sorry. Good luck with debugging.

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! IT WAS A COMPLETELY STUPID MISTAKE, IM AN IDIOT!!, BUT AN IDIOT LEARNING RAILS, WHEN I RAN MY LAST MIGRATION, I DIDNT POPULATE THE DEPARTMENT TABLE!!! WHAT A BANANA!